# Floating DIVs, one absolute width other relative width?

Tags: html

There is probably a simple answer, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Code:

```
<body>
  <div class='left'>
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want `.left` to be `width:100px` and `.right` to be the remaining width of `<body>`, but for the life of me, I can't get it.

I have:

```
<style>
.left{
 float:left;
 width:100px;
}
body{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
.right{
 float:left;
 width:85%;
}
</style>
```

But of course `85%` won't fill `<body>`. Any suggestions? I know it's simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.right { margin: 0 0 0 100px; } /* remove the float and width */
```

This will not work if you have elements inside `.right` which `clear`, otherwise it will.

Comment: unfortunately, I have `clear:both` in some elements inside `.right`

Comment: But, I got them all changed. Thanks for the fix!